# How to find the area of an isosceles triangle without using trigonometry?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area

I have an isosceles  triangle with equal sides $10$ unit, angle between them is $30^\circ$. I need to be confirmed that the area of this triangle can be found in any method other than using any kind of trigonometry. I tried Heron's formulae, but did not get any fruitful result.

Comment: Area of a triangle without trigonometry? It is preposterous. I think you mean something else. Trigonometry is the study of relationships involving lengths and angles of triangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [circumscribed circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle) and it's radius $R$. By [inscribed angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) theorem you get, that $|c|=|R|$, where $c$ is third side of your triangle $a=b=10$. Now you have formula $\displaystyle S=\frac{abc}{4R}$, where $S$ is area of triange. So:

$$S=\frac{10 \cdot 10 \cdot c}{4R}=\frac{100}{4}=25$$

Answer (score 2):

Try drawing an altitude from one of the $75$ degree angles to the opposite 10-unit side.  You should be able to determine the length of this altitude using a 30-60-90 triangle.

Comment: And furthermore, note that the leftover portion is similar to half the original triangle bisected at the 30 degree angle.

Comment: Using your hint ,applied on $\triangle ABC$ ,where  $AB=AC =10 $ cm. and $\angle BAC=30^ \circ ,BD \perp AC $, I see that $\triangle ABC= \frac 12 \times 10 \times BD=5BD$ where $BD=\sqrt {10^2-AD^2}$. Now,I am stuck. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I'll follow the hint of paw88789. Consider the following triangle

[image]

We have $\vert \overline{CA} \vert = \vert \overline{CB}\vert = 10$ and $\sphericalangle{ACB} = 30^{\circ}$. Now draw the height $\overline{BH}$ through $B$. We have $\sphericalangle BHC = 90^{\circ}$, therefore $\sphericalangle CBH = 60^{\circ}$. The Triangle HBC is half an equilateral triangle and therefore $\vert\overline{BH}\vert = \frac{10}{2}=5$. 
The area of the triangle is then
$$\frac12\vert \overline{AC}\vert \cdot \vert \overline{HB}\vert = \frac12 \cdot 10 \cdot 5 = 25. $$